# What can we get by row/column addition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Let $\Bbb K$ be a field and let ${\bf M} \in {\Bbb K}^{n \times n}$ be a full rank matrix. Applying elementary row and column operations, one can transform $\bf M$ into the identity matrix. What can we achieve when only row/column addition is allowed? By row/column addition, I mean replacing a row/column by the sum of that row/column and a multiple of another row/cloumn.

It is clear that the determinant remains the same. But can any two matrices $n\times n$ of full rank and the same determinant be transformed into each other by row and column addition?

---

**Example**

In the comments, I was asked to transform the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 0&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

into the identity. Here is how this can be done, though I am not sure if this is the optimal way.

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&{0}\\ 1&{1}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&{1}\\ 0&{1}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 0&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ -2&{1}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&-\frac{1}{2}\\ 0&{1}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: How would you transform $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$ into the identity?

Comment: If you can transform any matrix of form $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\ 0&b\end{pmatrix}$, where $ab=1$ into identity matrix maybe it can be extended for any matrix via geometrical interpretation..

Comment: In other words, what can one get via left- and right-multiplication by [Frobenius matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_matrix)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $\ k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n\in K\ $, with $\ \det(M)=\prod_\limits{i=1}^nk_i\ $, then there exists a sequence, $\ R_1,R_2,\dots,R_m\ $  of row operations of the specified form such that
$$
R_mR_{m-1}\dots R_1M=\text{diag}\big(k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n\big)\ .
$$
The key to doing this is that there exist sequences of row operations of the specified kind that will allow you to:

- swap any two rows and simultaneously multiply one of them by $\ {-}1\ ;$ and
- simultaneously multiply one row by an arbitrary non-zero constant $\ \alpha\ $ and any other row by its inverse $\ \alpha^{-1}\ $.

Here is how you can carry out the first of these operations:
\begin{align}
r_i'&=r_i+r_j\\
r_j'&=r_j-r_i'=-r_i\\
r_i''&=r_i'+r_j'=r_j\ .
\end{align}
After this sequence of operations, the new $\ i^\text{th}\ $ row, $\ r_i''=r_j\ ,$ will be the original $\ j^\text{th}\ $ row, and the new $\ j^\text{th}\ $ row, $\ r_j'={-}r_i\ ,$ will be the negative of the original $\ i^\text{th}\ $ row.

The second of the two above-mentioned operations can be performed as follows
\begin{align}
r_i'&=r_i+r_j\\
r_j'&=r_j+(\alpha-1)r_i'=\alpha r_j+(\alpha-1)r_i\\
r_i''&=r_i'-\alpha^{-1}r_j'=\alpha^{-1}r_i\\
r_j''&=r_j'-\alpha(1-\alpha)r_i''=\alpha r_j\ .
\end{align}
After this sequence of operations, the new $\ i^\text{th}\ $ row, $\ r_i''=\alpha^{-1}r_i\ $, will be the original $\ i^\text{th}\ $ row multiplied by $\ \alpha^{-1}\ $, and the new $\ j^\text{th}\ $ row, $\ r_j''=\alpha r_j\ $, will be the  the original $\ j^\text{th}\ $ row multiplied by $\ \alpha\ $.

Since any matrix obtained by applying row or column operations of the specified form to $\ M\ $ must always have full rank, every such matrix must have at least one non-zero entry in every column and can never have a column which is a linear combination of other columns.  Therefore, by subtracting suitable multiples of a row with a non-zero entry in the $\ j^\text{th}\ $ column from the other rows, you can reduce all the other entries in that column to zero.  If the non-zero entry is not in the $\ j^\text{th}\ $ row you can get it there by applying an operation of the first kind described above.  After doing this you will then have a matrix in which the only non-zero entry in the $\ j^\text{th}\ $ column is in the $\ j^\text{th}\ $ row. By applying this procedure successively to all the columns of $\ M\ $ (in any order you please) you can therefore reduce it to a matrix of the form $\ \text{diag}\big(\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots,\mu_n\big)\ $ with $\ \prod_\limits{i=1}^n\mu_i=\det(M)\ $.  Note that as you apply this procedure you will never have a column whose only non-zero entries are in the same rows as those columns  containing a single non-zero entry, because such a column would then be a linear combination of those latter columns.

You can now apply operations of the second kind described above to the rows of $\ \text{diag}\big(\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots,\mu_n\big)\ $ to multiply the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ row by $\ \frac{k_i}{\mu_i}\ $ and the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ row  by $\ \frac{\mu_i}{k_i}\ $.  The matrix you will then end up with is
$$
\text{diag}\left(k_1,k_2,\dots,\frac{\prod_\limits{i=1}^n\mu_i}{\prod_\limits{i=1}^{n-1}k_i}\right)=\text{diag}\big(k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n\big)\ ,
$$
since $\ \prod_\limits{i=1}^n\mu_i=\det(M)\ $ and $\ \prod_\limits{i=1}^{n-1}k_i=\frac{\det(M)}{k_n}\ $.